# Error when run npm start || grunt

Tags: node.js, express, npm, gruntjs, mean-stack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19FEe.png)

I have this error when I tried to run MEAN.JS Application using (npm start OR grunt).

*note : i didn't put any code in the project i'm just generate MEAN.js application and try to run it and faced me this problem

What is the problem?

Comment: Please consider adding the code creating this error, as it is not clear what might trigger the error

Comment: i'm just create new MEAN.js project as documentation

Comment: Its also just better if you post the Error as part of your question instead of linking to an external message.

Comment: Looks like grunt-node-inspector is not installed. Did yoou try to run npm i `grunt-node-inspector`? or just `npm i` in the root of your project?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa yes i'm try to run npm i grunt-node-inspector but nothing happen